# オブジェクトを一時的に使用できないようにする方法

Tags: c#, unity3d

オブジェクトを非表示にするのではなくオブジェクトをn秒後になるまで使えなくするといった
仕様にしたいのですが、方法はありますでしょうか

Comment: 「使えなくする」が具体的にはどういう状態なのか分かりません。オブジェクトは、「使わなければ使われない」と思います。もう少し詳細説明するか具体的な質問でお願いします。

予想では、コライダをOFFにする感じになりそうではありますが。

Answer (score 2):

「使えなくする」の意図するところがまだ分かりませんが、そのオブジェクトにスクリプトを付けて（付いていればその中で）「処理中」というフラグを用意して「処理できない時間です」という判断をしたらいいかと思います。

```
bool isActive = false;

public void StartAction() {
    if (isActive) return;        // 「処理中」なので何もしない

    StartCoroutine(DoAction());
}

Enumerator DoAction() {
    isActive = true;

    // 何か処理

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(10.0f);    // 10秒間
    isActive = false;
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

一旦、オブジェクトをコピーしてn秒後に戻すとかはどうでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

staticメンバに前回実行した時間を記録しておいて、メソッド実行時に現在時間と比較して、実行可能な時間帯でなければ待機する、という形で実装してみてはいかがでしょうか。
オブジェクトが同時に複数存在するときに、ちょっと複雑になりそうですが……。